# How to let ng-disabled directive work with isolated scope

Tags: scope, angularjs

Recently I have to make a Input element work with both ng-disabled and an custom directive which use isolated scope to evaluate expression just like what ng-disabled is doing, somehow, the custom directive works fine but ng-disabled doesn't, since it only evaluate expression within the isolated scope.

The custom directive is quite simple like:

```
angular
  .module('directives', [])
  .directive('conditionalAutofocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            condition:'&conditionalAutofocus'
        },
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.condition()) {
                attrs.$set('autofocus','true');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

while the page looks like:

```
<input name="pin"
       ng-model="pin"
       type="password"
       required
       ng-disabled="names == null"
       conditional-autofocus="names != null" />
```

Anybody already has solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance!
Yanni

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your issue?

Comment: Who is downvoting the lower answers? For christ sake people, downvoting is for unsafe and gross conceptual errors... and I know gross conceptual errors at least as well as anyone else...

Answer (score 20):

I had this same issue, and the easiest solution imho. is to use the isolated scope to inherit the property of ngDisabled.

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('conditionalAutofocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            condition:'&conditionalAutofocus',
            disabled:'=ngDisabled'
        },
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.condition()) {
                attrs.$set('autofocus','true');
            }
            if(scope.disabled){
                //is disabled
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Might only work for restrict : 'E'. Have not tested others**

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem lately. I wanted to disable a button in isolated scope and use this nice angular `ng-disabled` directive. 
After some digging I came to a solution like this:

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs){

    $scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, function(newVal){
        element.prop('disabled', newVal);
    });

    //...
}
```

To evaluate the `ng-diabled` expression instead of `$scope` just jump to `$scope.$parent` and all your variables will be avaliable. Unfortunatly manually setting the disabled property is required.

Answer (score 2):

OK, for my own case above my solution is to change the implementation of directive, not use isolated scope anymore:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('conditionalAutofocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.conditionalAutofocus, function(){
                if (scope.$eval(attrs.conditionalAutofocus)) {
                    element.focus();
                }else{
                    element.blur();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a bi-directional binding to the parent scope in your isolated scope definition. Then add a watch on the isolated scope property. This just duplicates the code in the ngReadonly directive.

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('conditionalAutofocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            condition: '&conditionalAutofocus',
            isReadonly: '=ngReadonly'
        },
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.condition()) {
                attrs.$set('autofocus','true');
            }

            scope.$watch('isReadonly', (value) => {
                attrs.$set('readonly', !!value);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of the complexity of the other answers.  The problem is that your Directive doesn't even know wtf ng-Disabled is.  If you want to use ng-Disabled in your template, you have to inject it into your scope or requirements.  For example, this **Will NOT** work:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-disabled="fieldDisabled" />',
        scope:{ something: '=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.something = attrs.something;
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.fieldDisabled = false;
            $scope.myAction = function() {
                $scope.fieldDisabled = true;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

But the following **Will** work:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-disabled="fieldDisabled" />',
        scope:{ something: '=', lol: '=ngDisabled' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.something = attrs.something;
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.fieldDisabled = false;
            $scope.myAction = function() {
                $scope.fieldDisabled = true;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the only change is `lol: '=ngDisabled'`.  That makes it work because now your directive knows what ngDisabled is.  You don't have to use `lol` or do any other special wiring.  You can use your controller just like any other controller now with your own variables.